# Trajectory of point mass confined to move inside a square

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A rigid square of mass $M$ rests on a horizontal plane where it is free to move with no friction. Inside it lies a point mass $m$, also free to move with no friction. Assuming that the square is initially still and the particle has a velocity $v_0$ which makes an angle $\theta$ with one of the sides of the square and that all collisions are perfectly elastic, determine the trajectory of the square.

This question was asked in an admission exam in an Italian university but I am unsure on how to approach it. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you familiar with conservation of momentum, angular momentum and energy?

Comment: You know how the centre of mass of the system moves, and you know the centre of mass must always lie within the square.

Comment: @Bort Yes I am familiar with all those concepts however I am quite unsure of what they are expecting of me in this question. The system will have 5 degrees of freedom (4 coming from the positions of the centre of the square and the particle and the last coming from the rotation about the centre of the square) so I would have to solve a system with at least 5 equations which seems to be impossible to do in an exam setting. Do you think they are expecting a merely qualitative description or is there something else going on that I am missing?

Comment: @LorenzoCatani I don't think they expect any calculations but rather physical argumentation by using conservation of momentum, angular momentum and energy as gandalf61 started. The most interesting part of the question is actually the angle $\theta$ because you will either have closed trajectories (in the center of mass system) or not closed trajectories for the point mass $m$.